# Magento 2.4 allow admin to add out of stock product from admin order

Tags: magento, magento2

In magento 2.4 we can not add out of stock product while placing order from admin. I have requirement that admin should be able to order from admin side even the products are out of stock. I see the backorder but I want it only for admin side.